# Apache Nifi slow cluster issue

Tags: performance, apache-nifi, sizing

I am using a Apache nifi for one of my clickstream projects to do some ETL.

I am getting traffic around **300 messages per second** currently with the following infra:

- RAM - 16 GB
- Swap - 6 GB
- CPU - 16 cores
- Disk - 100GB (Persistance not required)
- Cluster - 6 nodes

The entire cluster UI has become extremely slow with the following issues

- Processors giving back pressure when some failure happens, which consumes lot of threads
- Provenance writing becomes very slow
- Heartbeat across nodes becomes slow
  [Cluster Heart beat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2hmk.png)

I have the following questions on the setup

- Is RPG use recommended, as it is a HTTP call, which i using to spread
  across all the nodes, as there is an existing issue with EMQTT
  process for consumer group.
- What is the recommended value of thread count that should be allotted
  per core?
- What are the guidelines for infrastructure sizing
- What are the tuning parameters for a large cluster with high incoming requests and lot of heavy JSON parsing for transformation

Comment: What's the heap size that you had configured for NiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A couple of suggestions**

- Yes RPG usage is recommended, at least from what I've experienced, RPG seems to offer better distribution. Take a look at [3] below
- Some processors are CPU intensive then others so there's no clear cut answer for what value can be set for `Concurrent Tasks`. This is more of trial and error or testing and fine tuning approach that you'd have to master. One suggestion is, if you set too many `Concurrent Tasks` for a CPU intensive processor, it will have serious impact on the nodes.
- Hortonworks have made a detailed guide regarding this. I've provided the link below. [1]

**Some best practices and handy guides:**

- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/7882/hdfnifi-best-practices-for-setting-up-a-high-perfo.html
- http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2016/11/22/nifi-jolt/
- https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/